# How to install pitivi

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I followed the instructions given in [How do I compile and install the latest PiTiVi 0.15.2?](http://goo.gl/q4IhM)

I can see pitivi in the launch bar but noting happens if I click on it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11):

try this:

```
sudo apt-get install pitivi
```

Comment: Thanks wair 92. Do you know other efficient video editor tools ?

Comment: you can try  Kdenlive or Avidemux, but do not expect any miracle.